# What is the use of volatile keyword?

Tags: c++, c

What is the use of volatile keyword in C/C++? What is the difference between declaring a variable `volatile` and not declaring it as `volatile`?

Comment: Additionally, [getting your compiler to agree that it's volatile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642568/how-do-i-know-if-gcc-agrees-that-something-is-volatile) sometimes takes a bit of work.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72552/c-when-has-the-volatile-keyword-ever-helped-you and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437527/why-do-we-use-volatile-keyword-in-c

Comment: Related: *[Why is volatile needed in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246127/why-is-volatile-needed-in-c/)*

Answer (score 32):

The `volatile` qualifier on a variable tells the compiler that whenever you access this variable, its value has to be loaded from memory, and that the compiler may assume nothing about this value from previous stores it has effected.

So it is appropriate whenever you have situations where a variable may have a value that can not be foreseen in the current "thread of execution" (in a broad sense). This includes:

- hardware registers
- status variables in signal handlers
- live variables that are used after
  unexpected jumps such as `goto`,
  `switch`/`case`, or, more important,
  `setjmp`/`longjmp`.

`volatile` is also necessary (but not sufficient!) for atomic access to thread shared variables to which the access is not mutexed. For that purpose `volatile` is by no means sufficient to guarantee the atomic access, even if it is just for reading. For that, you'd have to use special instructions of the CPU that are not modeled (or interfaced) by the abstract machine of the current C standard, C99. The next standard, C1X, is supposed to have such primitives.

Comment: As it isn't sufficient, it actually isn't necessary either. It just doesn't help. :-)

Comment: @Bo, it is necessary in conjunction with with the special instructions that I mention, and will also be needed by the new interfaces that are in the works.

Answer (score 12):

Volatile tells the compiler that the variable might change without it knowing - so it shouldn't optimise it away.

The only time I have ever needed it was in the days of ISA cards when you read a memory address to get the data from the bus. There was also a bug in the compiler which meant volatile didnt work!

It can also be useful in some parallel / mutli-threaded code

Comment: It's also used quite frequently in embedded systems where various registers and devices are mapped to memory addresses.

Comment: Yes that's what I needed it for, on 16bit ISA you had to read the same address twice to get the high/low bytes. Unfortunately MS C++ decided that these two bytes were always equal!

Comment: 'volatile' is frequency misused for crude synchronization primitives. Pretty much every time you see the keyword 'volatile' outside of a device driver, you should read it as 'bug'. It's almost never the right way to do it... unless you're the author of a synchronization primitive.

Comment: I think volatile bool can be used as a Mutex but yes, unless it's something todo with HW it raises a flag

Answer (score 5):

Volatile tells to compiler that this value might change and the compiler should not do any optimization on it. An example of it.

```
/** port to read temperature **/
#define PORTBASE 0x40000000

unsigned int volatile * const port = (unsigned int *) PORTBASE; 

for(;;)
{
  if(*port == 300)
  {
     /** shutdown the system **/
  }

}
```

If port is not volatile, then the compiler will assume that the value cannot be changed. It will never do the checking if *port == 300. However, the value can be changed based on the sensor. We put volatile to tell compiler that don't do any optimization on it. Thumb rule is when using the memory mapped registers, whose value can change based on the circumstance, then use volatile keyword.

Answer (score 1):

For most C programs, the purpose of an object is to hold the last thing that was written by code in the current execution context ("thread", CPU core, etc.).  The easiest way for a compiler to keep track of an object's contents is to allocate space in storage, and treat reads and writes of that variable as reads and writes of that storage, but the storage itself does not represent the purpose of the code--it merely represents a means to an end.  Given `unsigned x;`, if a compiler sees `x+=3; x+6;`, the easiest way to generate code would be to fetch x, add 3, store the result to x, then fetch x, add 6, and store that result.  The intermediate load and store, however, are only needed when the compiler doesn't know how to achieve the same effect some other way.  A better compiler given such code would often be able to simplify it to simply add 9.

Especially in embedded or systems code, however, the *purpose* of a program may include loading and storing certain values from certain storage locations in a certain sequence.  Many real-world machines perform I/O by having hardware which is triggered by loads and stores of certain objects, and performs various actions in response.  For example, it would not be uncommon to have an object which would under the right conditions cause any character sent to it to be passed along to a terminal.  Storing 'H' and then 'i' to SERTX, for example, might send `Hi`.  Having a compiler try to simplify or consolidate such sequences (e.g. deciding to omit the store of 'H') would render the programs useless.  A `volatile` qualifier indicates to the compiler that while it would be free to consolidate most accesses to most objects, there are a few for which such accesses need to be performed precisely as written.  Effectively, one could imagine that for each scalar type (e.g. "unsigned") there are functions

```
int volatile_load_unsigned(unsigned volatile *p);
void volatile_store_unsigned(unsigned volatile *p, usigned value);
```

whose behavior the compiler knows nothing about, and thus code like:

```
extern volatile unsigned x;
x+=3;
x+=6;
```

would be interpreted by the compiler as equivalent to:

```
extern volatile int x;
volatile_store_unsigned(&x, volatile_load_unsigned(&x)+3);
volatile_store_unsigned(&x, volatile_load_unsigned(&x)+6);
```

In fact, the machine code to perform a volatile store is on most systems
the same as the code for an ordinary store (and does not generate any kind
of function call) but only the part of the compiler that generates the
final machine code would "know" that--everything else should treat the
code as though it was a function whose effects the compiler knew nothing
about.

Unfortunately, in the name of "optimization", some compilers have ceased
treating volatile accesses as calls to opaque functions.  If code calls
a function whose inner workings the compiler knows nothing about, it
must assume that function may access any and all objects whose address
has ever been exposed to the outside world.  Applying such treatment to
`volatile`-qualified variables will allow code to construct an object in
ordinary storage, taking advantage of the ability to consolidate loads
and stores, store the address of that object to a volatile-qualified
pointer, triggering some other process which outputs the buffer.  Code
would need to test volatile-qualified object to ensure that the contents
of the buffer had been output completely before doing anything else
with that storage, but on implementations that follow the "opaque function" model the compiler would ensure that all writes to the storage which occurred in code before the volatile store that triggers the output operation would in fact generate store instructions which precede the instruction for the volatile store.

Some compiler writers think that it is more useful to have compilers assume they don't need to generate stores to non-qualified variables before performing accesses to volatile-qualified ones.  Certainly the Standard does not require that implementations acknowledge the possibility that writing to a volatile variable might trigger actions that could affect other things, but that doesn't mean that a quality compiler for systems where such constructs can be useful shouldn't support them.  Unfortunately, the fact that the authors of the Standard didn't want to mandate behaviors which would be useful on some systems but not others, has been interpreted as suggesting that compiler writers shouldn't support such behaviors even on systems where they are useful.

Note that on some processors, ensuring that one CPU executes instructions in a certain sequence may not be sufficient to ensure that the effects of that instruction occur in sequence.  Some processors include configuration options so that operations on some parts of memory will be guaranteed to occur in order even when that would reduce execution speed, and some processors include other means of controlling execution order, but such issues are separate from `volatile`.  On a quality implementation, `volatile` will ensure that the processor is at least made aware of all reads and writes that need to occur; a programmer may need to perform additional steps to ensure that the processor actually perform them as indicated, but telling the processor to complete all pending operations before it does anything else won't do any good if the compiler hasn't told the processor that something needs to get written.

Answer (score 0):

Volatile tells the compiler that the value of variable can be change from outside the scope of your code for ex.

```
{
 int x; 
 int y;
}
```

The value of x and y are limited to the scope but in case if we are modifying its value from somewhere outside then it should be marked as volatile because compiler will keep these values in temporary register and always give the same value instead of giving the modified value.

So in such cases volatile must be used in order to get the recent value of that particular variable.

Answer (score 0):

volatile restrict the compiler not to optimize the use of particular variable that is declared volatile in to the code.

**Difference between variable with volatile and without it**

**Variable Without volatile**

```
int main()    
{    
    int a = 5;

    while(a == 5)  //compiler replace variable **'a'** with 5 as optimization purpose    
    {        
    }

    if(a==5)//compiler replace **'a'** with 5 as optimization purpose    
    {    
    }

    return 0;    
}
```

in above code compiler assume that the value of the variable **'a'** will always be 5,so compiler replace all **'a'** with 5 as optimization purpose.

**Variable with volatile**

But some variables value changed by outside interrupt,so here we always need to get that variables value directly from Memory.For this purpose we use **volatile**.

```
volatile int a=5;

while(a==5) //compiler will npt optimize the variable **'a'** and always get the value of **'a'** from Memory
```

Comment: "*compiler will npt optimize the variable 'a' and always get the value of 'a' from Memory*" The first part is true, but the second part is not. For example, the CPU may still bypass the access from memory and this happens on almost all modern systems.

Answer (score -3):

when we use the simple non volatile variable at that time the compiler will try to optimize the code, for example if you are using b=a*a*a; then it will be used like b=a*3; but when you use the volatile keyword while declaring the variable "a" , then the optimization wont take place for the value of "a", and each and every time the value will be fetched from the memory, because volatile Qualifier will allow other hardware as well as the process to change the value of the variable.

Comment: 1) a*a*a != a*3, 2) the <code>volatile</code> qualifier doesn't <em>allow</em> the variable to be changed -- it just warns the compiler that the variable <em>may have gotten</em> changed elsewhere.

Comment: agree with @ChristianSeverin