# Usefulness of volatile in concurrent programming since C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, volatile

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12878500/1348273) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5190753/1348273) answer. I've also searched the book [C++ Concurrency in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/c-plus-plus-concurrency-in-action) and found no discussion about `volatile` nor any example using it. Looks like it's not designed for concurrency at all. So for concurrent programming, is it sufficient to just use atomic, mutex, etc., and forget about `volatile`? Any cases where `volatile` may be needed for concurrency issues?

Comment: No, there aren't any -- volatile was designed more for things like handling memory-mapped hardware registers.  For concurrent programming, it's simply not the right tool for the job.

Comment: There’s a reason it’s not mentioned, and it’s the same reason that pirate ships and bananas and Wittgenstein’s Tractatus aren’t mentioned.

Comment: @nolbdnilo Arrrr!

Comment: This question has been asked and answered a lot on SO. Problem is, some of the green check-mark answers with many thumbs up are just wrong.  The short answer is, if you are not interfacing with memory-mapped hardware, just forget you ever heard of `volatile`.  What you don't remember you know won't hurt you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, in  C++ the `volatile` keyword tells the compiler that must not optimize the variable in any way shape or form. This can be useful when dealing with memory that can be changed from outside of your own code e.g a hardware register on a custom board.
For more in depth guide about volatile you should read [Volatile vs. volatile
By Herb Sutter](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/volatile-vs-volatile/212701484?pgno=2)

Answer (score 3):

**`volatile` and `atomic` are two orthogonal concepts. So their combination change the program semantic, otherwise they would not be orthogonal!**

*atomicity* causes constraints on sequencing ( included atomicity of read and write).

*volatility* causes constraints on the elidability of accesses to the variable.

`volatile` does not cause any sequencing between thread, nevertheless it is still usefull. Consider this program, that show a progress bar, the computation is performed in one thread, while another thread is responsible for the graphics:

```
//thread A
extern std::atomic<int> progress;
//
void compute(){
  progress=0;
  //do something;
  progress=1;
  //do something;
  progress=2;
  //[...] a 100 time.
  }
```

Inside the function compute, the compiler notice that `progress` is never read but just written many time. So it can optimize the code to:

```
void compute(){
  //do many thing;
  progress=100;
  }
```

By declaring `volatile atomic<int> progress;` all the writes will not be collapsed, and the memory order will ensure that operations will be performed inbetween of all these writes.

See also:

- [N4455 No Sane Compiler Would Optimize Atomic](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4455.html)
- [P0063R1: When Should Compiler Optimize Atomics](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0062r1.html), where my example comes from.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is not correct. Volatile makes absolutely no memory order promises. Atomic DOES.  Every language lawyer I have heard chime in on this, including the Right Hon. Bjarne Stoustrup, has said not to use `volatile` on anything higher than silicon and sparks, no exceptions.

Comment: Nonsense: the compiler cannot optimize accesses to atomic objects away unless it can prove that there is no other thread possibly accessing the values.

Comment: @JiveDadson Unfortunatly there is always a gap between what should be and necessity.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Try to prove what you say in this [case](https://godbolt.org/g/nEBEcz). In this case an optimizer has the right to colapse all the writes to progress.

Comment: @Oliv: why don’t *you* prove that your assertion is correct? Note 34.2 [atomics.order] paragraph 12 and in particular that the *should* similarly applies to object even if they are `volatile`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl *Implementations should make atomic stores visible to atomic loads within a reasonable amount of time.*  What do you believe this sentence mean? Do you believe that each time their is a store a load should happen?? A store is visible if a load is performed on that store or on a store performed subsquently to that store!!

Comment: @DietmarKühl I have added two sentences at the top of my answer. Don't you think these sentences form an example of [petitio principii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question).

Comment: @DietmarKühl Denial is a river in Egypt… More seriously, what you are implying is that a compiler is obliged to ensure that each logically possible interleaving of accesses on an atomic variable has a nonzero probability. I'm pretty sure that is stated nowhere in the standard. Instead, I am pretty sure that which interleaving occurs is unspecified behavior because it is not stated in atomics.order, therefore redundant store elimination on (non-volatile) atomics is allowed under the as-if rule. Also, please don't ask of Oliv to prove a universal negative.