# Use of atomic<> and code reordering? Stroustrup example

Tags: c++

I'm reading Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed Page 1204 and the following example is used.  I'm curious, what would be the possible **re-ordering** of this code?  Is it optimization?  If so, for example, would making `volatile bool x_init` also prevent the optimization or reordering?

```
X x;
mutex lx;
atomic<bool> x_init {false};

void some_code()
{
    if (!x_init) {
        lx.lock();
        if (!x_init) {
// ... initialize x ...
            x_init = true;
        }
        lx.unlock();
    }
// ... use x ...
}
```

Stroustrup Quote:

> Had init_x not been atomic, instruction reordering could have moved
> the initialization of x ahead of the apparently unrelated test of
> init_x. Making init_x atomic prevents that.

Comment: `volatile` doesn't give strong enough guarantees when multithreading. Here's some reading on `volatile`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4437555/4581301 and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5190753/4581301 Specifically, `volatile` will not prevent re-ordering.

Comment: If multiple threads may call `some_code` simultaneously, and `x_init` is not of `atomic` type, then such a program would exhibit undefined behavior by way of a data race. Beyond that, I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik my question is specific to Stroustrup's mention of instruction reordering and what could be reordered

Comment: @user4581301 I was thinking of the how the code would be reordered if atomic had not been used, and using volatile and removal of volatile as another mechanism to explain possible reordering

Comment: Forget about volatile. It has nothing to do with atomicity.  Only time you should really be using volatile is when working with hardware.